# Could asp.net unite autocad and mathcad or matlab system?

Tags: asp.net, matlab, autocad

Needs that autocad uses value from mathcad or matlab? Could I use for it asp.net?

Comment: ASP.NET is a framework for developing web sites and applications. It doesn't have much in common with AutoCAD or MathCAD. Could you be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1):

Matlab allows to use its API in different projects written with C#, Java etc.

You need to create Matlab project and convert it to .NET library. Than you will be able to use Matlab API as .NET library in ASP.NET projects.

*But as I remember you required Matlab to be installed anyway.*

MathCad does not allow to communicate with other frameworks.